# Ethereum Post-Merge Full Node

Tags: go-ethereum, full-node, lighthouse

I am trying to run a full mainnet node on AWS EC2. I received the following warning `WARN [09-29|12:33:51.514] Post-merge network, but no beacon client was seen. Please launch one to follow the chain!`, which I understand I need to run consensus client (`lighthouse` in my case) along with execution client (`geth` in my case).

I set up my geth client with the following code:

```
sudo geth --mainnet \
    --datadir "/data/ethereum" \
    --http --http.api="personal,eth,net,web3,txpool" \
    --ws --ws.api="personal,eth,net,web3,txpool" \
    --port "35555" \
    --authrpc.vhosts="localhost" \
    --authrpc.jwtsecret="/home/ubuntu/jwtsecret"\
    --authrpc.port="8580"\
    --http.port="8546"
```

Q1: Now, out of `vhosts`, `authrpc.port` and `http.port`, which port is the one my `lighthouse` client needs to connect to? I thought it is `--authrpc.port` but I receive following error when I run my `lighthouse client`.

`Sep 29 12:41:29.154 CRIT Failed to update execution head         error: ExecutionLayerMissing, service: beacon`

How I start my light-house client.

```
sudo ./lighthouse beacon_node
    --network mainnet \
    --datadir "/data/ethereum" \
    --http \
    --execution-endpoint= http://127.0.0.1:8580 \
    --execution-jwt= /home/ubuntu/jwtsecret
```

Q2: Do I need to wait my `geth` client to fully synced before I start my `lighthouse` client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `--authrpc.port` is what your consensus client needs to connect to your execution client (geth). If you don't specify anything when you start yout geth, the port `8551` will be used by default. Then you can start your consensus client with `--execution-endpoint=http://localhost:8551`.
2. Correct. Your geth will not start sync unless lighthouse is synced fully.

Answer (score 0):

add JWT:
https://github.com/remyroy/ethstaker/blob/main/merge-goerli-prater.md

remove testnets:

geth.service:
--goerli \

lighthousebeacon.service:
--network prater \

add geth.service:
--syncmode full \

get latest version beacon node, today is lighthouse-v3.2.1-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.tar.gz.